# Redirect Non WWW to WWW

Tags: asp.net-core

On an ASP.Net Core application startup I have:

```
RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions(); 

rewriteOptions.AddRedirectToHttps();

applicationBuilder.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

When in Production I need to redirect all Non WWW to WWW.

For example:

```
domain.com/contact > www.domain.com/contact
```

How can I do this using Rewrite Middleware?

Comment: www is outdated. Why would you force people to it? :)

Comment: I am no expert but I have been reading some posts like this one: https://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www. I see many sites redirecting non www to www. For example, Google, Invision, etc. But again, I am not expert. I am trying to figure which one is better.

Comment: Yeah I see the reasoning behind it, that's fair. Maybe we can standardize on something less annoying to read aloud like "web."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**.Net Core 5+**
As highlighted by @Rich. There is now an extension method on `RewriteOptions` for this purpose. See [`RewriteOptionsExtensions.AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.rewriteoptionsextensions.addredirecttowwwpermanent?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

---

You could create a custom rule by creating a class and implementing the `IRule` interface (see below). I think there must be a better way to construct the `redirectUrl` though.

```cs
public class CanonicalDomainRewriteRule : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Host.Value.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            string redirectUrl = $"{request.Scheme}://www.{request.Host}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = redirectUrl;
            response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

You can add this rule as follows in your `ConfigureServices` method:

```cs
RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
    .Add(new CanonicalDomainRewriteRule());

app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

See [Extensions and Options: IRule-based rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x#irule-based-rule) for further examples.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but could not this be done with a Regex using something like: .AddRedirect("redirect-rule/(.*)", "redirected/$1") but of course with the right rule?

Comment: Probably, but I can't help with that. Personally, I would probably find the above easier to read/maintain/extend.

Comment: From .Net Core 5+, there is now an extension method on `RewriteOptions` to support this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.rewriteoptionsextensions.addredirecttowwwpermanent?view=aspnetcore-5.0

ie.
`RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToWwwPermanent();`